# Callback function in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, table-functions

I have been doing some data transformation/processing in PL/SQL and I want to **eliminate duplicate code** from my package. This are the relevant code parts.

Input type for the table function:

```
type t_legs_cur is ref cursor return legs%rowtype;
```

Procedure that process one record:

```
procedure discontinuity_rule(p_leg in out nocopy legs%rowtype) as
begin
  null; --business logic here
end discontinuity_rule;
```

Table function that iterates over a cursor, process each row in cursors and pipes the output (if any):

```
function apply_discontinuity_rule(p_cur t_legs_cur)
  return t_legs pipelined
  order p_cur by (/* some fields */)    
  parallel_enable (partition p_cur by range (/* some fields */))
as
  v_leg legs%rowtype;
begin
  loop
    fetch p_cur into v_leg;
    exit when p_cur%notfound;

    discontinuity_rule(v_leg); --call back

    if v_leg.id is not null then
      pipe row (v_leg);
    end if;

  end loop;
end apply_discontinuity_rule;
```

There are several steps of transformation/processing, e.g. I would run the following select to do the some processing and apply some rules in a given order:

```
select * from table(trip_rules.generate_trips_from_legs(cursor(
  select * from table(trip_rules.apply_5_legs_rule(cursor(
    select * from table (trip_rules.apply_previous_city_rule(cursor(
      select * from table (trip_rules.apply_backhaul_rule(cursor(
        select * from table(trip_rules.apply_connection_time_rule(cursor(
          select * from table(trip_rules.apply_discontinuity_rule(cursor(
            select * from table(trip_rules.generate_legs_from_input(cursor(
              select * from INPUT_DATA
            )))
          )))
        )))
      )))
    )))
  )))
)));
```

This is all fine and dandy, only problem is, my trip_rule package contains many `apply_*_rule` functions. They all similar to the example `apply_discontinuity_rule`. The only difference is the actual procedure (`discontinuity_rule`) they call back.

SO, my question would be, how can I avoid to copy the code of the `apply_*` functions. Is there a more elegant way to do this then use a big if: `if p_rule_name == 'discontinuity_rule' then`

```
function apply_rule(p_cur t_legs_cur, p_rule_name in varchar2)
  return t_legs pipelined
  order p_cur by (/* some fields */)    
  parallel_enable (partition p_cur by range (/* some fields */))
as
  v_leg legs%rowtype;
begin
  loop
    fetch p_cur into v_leg;
    exit when p_cur%notfound;

    if p_rule_name == 'discontinuity_rule' then
      discontinuity_rule(v_leg);
    elsif p_rule_name == 'other_rule' then
      other_rule(v_leg);
    elsif p_rule_name == 'totally_other_rule' then
      totally_other_rule(v_leg);
    -- and so on...
    end if;

    if v_leg.id is not null then
      pipe row (v_leg);
    end if;

  end loop;
end apply_rule;
```

I also understand that it would be possible to create an anonymous PL/SQL block on the fly using the procedure name and execute it as dynamic SQL. I wonder if it can be done properly, without killing my performance. Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your giant IF statement is not duplicate code.

True, it has parts which resemble each other but this ...

```
elsif p_rule_name == 'other_rule' then
    other_rule(v_leg);
```

... is most definitely not the same as this ...

```
elsif p_rule_name == 'totally_other_rule' then
    totally_other_rule(v_leg);
```

Dynamic PL/SQL is something we should avouid unless there really is no alternative.  There is no need for it here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You're right, the big if is not that bad as having the `apply_*_rule` functions duplicated, which I had before I started to post this question. I came up with the big if while I was phrasing this question. And I will go for that unless there is a better option.